# Daypilot C# Get Selected Day

Tags: javascript, c#, calendar, daypilot

I am building a master rota using Daypilot. I only care about Monday -Sunday. I don't care about DATES, just DAYS. E.G a shift created on a Monday between 2-4 will be there every Monday between 2-4.

I am using the TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript to call the modal popup

Is there a way using this javascript to get the selected DAY.

E.G if they try and create a appointment on the weekly calender on a Monday, then "Monday" can be passed through?

```
    TimeRangeSelectedHandling="JavaScript"
    TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript="timeRangeSelected(start, end,$('#MainContent_DropDownList_Week').val(), $('#MainContent_DropDownListLocationMasterRota').val());"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the day of week from the start/end variables:

```
var startDow = start.getDayOfWeek();
var endDow = end.getDayOfWeek();
```

Both start and end variables hold a [DayPilot.Date](https://api.daypilot.org/daypilot-date-class/) object. See also [DayPilot.Date.getDayOfWeek()](https://api.daypilot.org/daypilot-date-getdayofweek/).

Your example modified:

```
TimeRangeSelectedHandling="JavaScript"
TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript="timeRangeSelected(start.getDayOfWeek(), end.getDayOfWeek(), $('#MainContent_DropDownList_Week').val(), $('#MainContent_DropDownListLocationMasterRota').val());"
```